# Get Contacts from social networking sites

Tags: 7

I am trying to import contacts from Social networking sites to Drupal using OpenInviter. Its working fine with Web mail Providers but when i am trying to get contacts from Social networking sites it is throwing error as

- Unable to get contacts.
- No contacts could be retrieved from your account.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Contact Importer](https://drupal.org/project/contact_importer) in conjunction with OpenInviter.  It could be that you do not have an app for the specific social network to give permissions to allow access to users' data.

While I was configuring [HybridAuth](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth), there were options to allow your site to access contacts of users.  This requires you acquire an API key for each social network you want to access, which means creating an app.  If you're still having issues I could set up an app on the social networks you would like to access, then configure hybridauth and see if you can access the contacts through its API.

Comment: Any other methods instead of using HybridAuth Module.

Comment: @prashanth are you using contact importer with openinviter?